# Cannot find the MySQL_EN="false" in MySQL setup on terminal with Zend package on my Mac.

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework, mamp

I am trying to setup Zend framework on my Mac and the O'Reilly guide says that I should see this line: MySQL_EN="false" in the terminal when I run the "sudo nano /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh" command. I am not able to see any such text and the terminal opens a blank text file. Can anyone help please?